# ListPlot with piecewise colors

Tags: plotting, color

I have a CSV file that specifies three real numbers `x, y, v`, and I need to generate a plot (`ListPlot`, joined) with the lines colored according to the value of `v`.

But let's consider the simplest case, where `v` can be `+1` or `-1`. Where values are `+1` the line should be green, and blue where `v` is `-1` (or solid/dotted).

For instance:

```
0, 0, +1 `
1, 1, +1 | < GREEN
2, 4, +1 /
3, 2, -1 ` < BLUE
4, 1, -1 /
5, 4, +1 ` < GREEN
```

Is there a way of using the values and produce a plot? The questions I've found are about using a color function, but in this case I have no function as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list = {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, 4, 1}, {3, 2, -1}, {4, 1, -1}, {5, 4, 1}};
```

**1.** You can `Partition` the input list to create separate lines and use the option `PlotStyle` to color pieces individually:

```
ListLinePlot[Partition[list[[All, ;; 2]], 2, 1], 
 PlotStyle -> (Rest[list[[All, -1]]] /. {1 -> Green, -1 -> Blue}) ]
```

[image]

**2.** You can use the options [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) and [`MeshShading`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshShading.html) as follows:

```
split = SplitBy[list, Last];
mesh = split[[All, -1, 1]];
meshshading =split[[All, 1, -1]] /. {1 -> Green, -1 -> Blue};

ListLinePlot[list[[All, {1, 2}]], Mesh -> {mesh}, MeshShading -> meshshading]
```

[image]